# Curl: Display progress bar but supress errors

Tags: curl

I have the following command:

```
curl --progress-bar -f url --output file | some command
```

Progress bar is send to some command for editing.
When file is not available `--output file` will fail to create file due to `-f` option.
I want to display progress bar but supress: `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500` in case file not available

Comment: `curl --progress-bar -f url --output file 2>/dev/null | some command` is what you are looking for, perhaps

Comment: it doesnt work it also supresses the provress bar

Comment: I believe if `curl` fails  then the progress bar is useless. If I use `curl --progress-bar --limit-rate 70B -f example.com --output file` will work successfully (and the progress bar will be shown). But if I use `curl --progress-bar --limit-rate 70B -f example.com/one --output file`  the command will fail and therefore the progress bar should not work.